# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quote' of undefinedprintQuote

Tags: javascript

The code, after few clicks, says this error on console and stops showing the quotes

I tried everything but all was in vain.
https://github.com/rishabh7977/random-quote-generator

Comment: Please [edit] the relevant code into your question.

Comment: This code sometimes return index that goes outside of array... a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length) + 1]; Remove +1 and you should be fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to take out the `+ 1` in your `getRandomQuote` function. It made it possible to have an index that was out of range, returning `undefined`.

```
function getRandomQuote() {
    return arrayQ[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayQ.length)];
};
```